# How do I make 'Double for loop(O(n^2))' into 'Single for loop(O(n))'?

Tags: java, performance

I am studying Algorithm and I am trying to make it much efficient way and cleaner way.

This is an algorithm that finds the values which are not duplicate and return the first value among them.

Here is my code below.

```
// example input of array.
int[] A = [2, 5, 1, 5, 1, 3, 9, 2];

// check pairs. And make them -1
// from 0 index to last index.
for(int i = 0 ; i < A.length ; i++){
    // from the next index to the last index ( the rest indices ).
    for(int j=i+1; j < A.length ; j++){
        // if ith value and jth value are euqal and never checked make them -1 so that you can mark they have been visited.
        if(A[i]==A[j] && A[i]>0){
            A[i]=-1; A[j]=-1; 
        }
    }
}

// find the first number among the left positive values.
for(int i = 0 ; i < A.length ; i++){
    if(A[i]>0) return A[i];
}
// if there is no positive value, return 0;
return 0;
```

As you can see, this is O(n^2). I am trying to make this much faster or looking cleaner. I think I can make this O(n), which means using only one for loop(not double for loop.) Do you think is it possible?

Comment: "_I think I can make this O(n). But I don't have any clues._" How could you think this can be done then ? ;)

Comment: **I think I can make this O(n)**, what is your idea, mind to share?

Comment: I mean, I think I can make it as one loop. But I don't know how. @AxelH

Comment: Please post the problem statement. It's easier to re-engineer a solution when you know what the code's supposed to do.

Comment: Same problem, how could you think this is possible if you don't know how... As for now, I would need to read your code to understand what you want to do, then find a better solution. Could you at least explain what it is doing and where you expect to improve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in @gabi13's answer, probably the simplest and most efficient way would be to use a O(nlogn) sorting algorithm and then traverse the array searching for the first element which is not equal to the next (or previous).

However, I'd like to clarify a bit further, as you seem to be confusing complexity concepts in your question.

Reducing two loops into one does not turn O(n²) into O(n), unless they are nested (but you ask for a way to discard the last loop, not the nested one).

Your first loop is the one causing O(n²), as it has 2 nested loops traversing the array. Even if you remove the last loop, your code will remain O(n²).

Despite your approach cannot turn into O(n) (see @gabe13's answer for an alternative approach O(nlogn)), your implementation can be optimized.

First, if you only need to focus on positive values, you don't need to check for pairs if A[i]<=0. Moving that condition outside the nested loop would improve efficiency.

Additionally, if your just want the first positive non-repeated element, it is enough to check in the first nested loop, only for A[i]>0, if you have failed to find a repetition (i.e. the nested loop ended without findind a pair). In that case, you already have your solution.

Comment: No, I meant nested for loop. I know time complexity. I wanted to remove the double for loop and make it into O(n) or any better way.

And I don't think it is possible because if the arr is [1, 1, 2, 2]. It will think 1 or 2 is not duplicated. And also in my code, I can skip the negative values. But O is the worst case. Your idea is better than mine. However, even if I put the condition for checking positive value. It is still
`O(n^2)`.

Comment: Sorting in O(nlog n) is not the most efficient way. Since this is integers, bucket sort would be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to return the first element not repeated or any? Because if you do not have to be the first, you can do it in O(nLGn). Sort the array with some method that takes logarithmic time, such as mergesort, and then traverses it by looking for one position is not the same as the next / previous one

Answer (score 1):

You could use an idea from integer sort. It's three loops, but they are not nested. It can handle negative numbers. The time complexity is `O(n+m)` where `n` is length of array and `m` is the difference between the maximum and the minimum value in the array.

Here is a working java example:

```
public class findDup {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr[] = { -4, -6, -4, 8, 9, 8, 9, 10, -3 };
        printNonDups(arr);
    }

    public static void printNonDups(int arr[]) {
    // Find max and min.                                                                                                                                                                                       

        int max=arr[0];
        int min=arr[0];

        // Find max and min. 
        // O(arr.length)
        for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
            if(arr[i]>max)
                max=arr[i];
            if(arr[i]<min)
                min=arr[i];
        }

        int tmp[] = new int[max-min+1];

        // Count the number of occurrences of each number.
        // O(arr.length) 
        for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) 
            tmp[arr[i]-min]++;

        // Print all unique values
        // O(max-min)
        for(int i=0; i<tmp.length; i++) 
            if(tmp[i]==1) {
                System.out.println(i+min);
                // break; // Uncomment to stop after first non-duplicate                                                                                                                                               
            }
    }
}
```

It's three loops, but they are not nested. It can handle negative numbers. The time complexity is `O(n+m)` where `n` is length of array and `m` is the difference between the maximum and the minimum value in the array.

Comment: @ChanjungKim I don't know how I thought, but I changed it to working java code now.

Answer (score 1):

So from what I understand you want to return the first value that is neither 0 nor duplicated in the next position, if there is none return 0?

How about:

```
for( int i=0; i<A.length-1;i++)
{ 
    if( A[i]>0 && A[i]!=A[i+1] ) return A[i];
}
return 0;
```

Of course if you also need to modify the array because you will keep on using it, you will need further logic.

Comment: after sorting, if the array is [1, 1, 2, 2] it will still return 1 even though it is duplicated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java, you can use [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

Code that uses `HashMap` to find the unduplicated number in a list:

```
public class NonDuplicateNumber {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {1,3,2,5,7,6,9,8,10,1,3,2,5,7,6,9,8,10,4};
        Map<Integer, Integer> countMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
            if(countMap.containsKey(arr[i])) {
                int count = countMap.get(arr[i]);
                count++;
                countMap.put(arr[i], count);
            } else {
                countMap.put(arr[i], 1);
            }
        }

        Set<Integer> keySet = countMap.keySet();
        for(Integer key : keySet) {
            int count = countMap.get(key);
            if(count == 1) {
                System.out.println("Non duplicate number: "+key);
            }
        }
    }
}
```